# flask + gunicorn + nginx web server fails with "502 bad gateway"

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, webhooks, gunicorn

I've been wrecking my mind over this issue for the past day. When i try to run these services on the same VM it works fine, but when i try to seperate the flask app from the nginx server, it just doesnt work. I'm trying to set up a simple webhook that simulates stock trading. These are the files im using:

hook.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, json, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    mountains = ['Everest', 'K2', 'Kilimanjaro']
    return render_template('index.html', mountain=mountains)

@app.route('/mountain/<mt>')
def mountain(mt):
    return "This is " + str(mt)

@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])

def hook():
    print(request.data)
    d = request.data
    r = json.loads(d.decode())
    if(r["action"] == 'buy'):
        buy_stock(name=r['name'], amount=r['amount'])
    elif(r["action"] == 'sell'):
        sell_stock(name=r['name'], amount=r['amount'])
    return r

def buy_stock(name, amount):
    print(f"this will buy {amount} {name} stock")

def sell_stock(name, amount):
    print(f"this will sell {amount} {name} stock")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

gunicorn.sh

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install net-tools -y


git clone https://github.com/useruser/stock_webhook.git stocks
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo apt install python3-venv -y

sudo python3 -m venv ~/env/stocks
sudo chown -R vagrant ~/env/stocks
source ~/env/stocks/bin/activate
pip install flask
pip install gunicorn

cd stocks
sudo tee -a ./wsgi.py >/dev/null <<'EOF'
from hook import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
EOF
deactivate
sudo chown -R vagrant ~/stocks

sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/system/stocks.service >/dev/null <<'EOF'
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve stocks Flask app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=vagrant
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/vagrant/stocks
Environment="PATH=/home/vagrant/env/stocks/bin"
ExecStart=/home/vagrant/env/stocks/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOF

sudo chmod 775 /home/vagrant
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start stocks
sudo systemctl enable stocks

sudo systemctl stop ufw
```

nginx.sh

```
sudo apt update
apt install nginx -y
sudo apt install net-tools -y

cat <<EOT > stocksapp
upstream stocksapp {
 server 10.0.1.121:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
location / {
  proxy_pass http://10.0.1.121;
}
location /webhook {
  proxy_pass http://10.0.1.121;
}
}

EOT

sudo mv stocksapp /etc/nginx/sites-available/stocksapp
sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/stocksapp /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/stocksapp

#starting nginx service
systemctl start nginx
systemctl enable nginx
systemctl restart nginx

sudo systemctl stop ufw
```

vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.hostmanager.enabled = true 
    config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
    
  ### gunicorn vm ###
     config.vm.define "app01" do |app01|
      app01.vm.box = "ubuntu/jammy64"
      app01.vm.hostname = "app01"
      app01.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.121"
      app01.vm.provision "shell", path: "gunicorn.sh", privileged: false
      app01.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
       vb.memory = "800"
     end
     end
     
    
  ### Nginx VM ###
    config.vm.define "web01" do |web01|
      web01.vm.box = "ubuntu/jammy64"
      web01.vm.hostname = "web01"
    web01.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.120"
  #  web01.vm.network "public_network"
    web01.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
       vb.gui = true
       vb.memory = "800"
     end
    web01.vm.provision "shell", path: "nginx.sh"  
  end
    
  end
```

For some reason everything i do returns 502 bad gateway. I thought this was a permissions issue on the flask folder but it wasnt (changed to 775 and reloaded). even local curl doesnt work, returns 500:

```
vagrant@app01:~$ curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:8080
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Checked for open ports with no issues:

```
vagrant@app01:~$ netstat -tupln | grep 8080
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
vagrant@app01:~$
```

ufw is down on both vms to be sure:

```
vagrant@web01:~$ sudo systemctl status ufw
○ ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2023-12-18 01:49:47 UTC; 30min ago
       Docs: man:ufw(8)
    Process: 3406 ExecStop=/lib/ufw/ufw-init stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 420 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 2ms

vagrant@app01:~$ sudo systemctl status ufw
○ ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2023-12-18 02:07:40 UTC; 12min ago
       Docs: man:ufw(8)
    Process: 3827 ExecStop=/lib/ufw/ufw-init stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 427 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 2ms
```